# Pythonのメソッドはオーバーライドされているのか

Tags: java, python

Javaではstaticメソッドはオーバーライドできないとされています。
たとえば、以下のようなコードはオーバーライドではないとされています。
(オーバーライドではなく、隠蔽(hiding)であるとされる)

```
class A {
    public static void a() { 
        System.out.println("A.a()");
    }
}   

class B extends A {
    public static void a() {
        System.out.println("B.a()");
    }
}
```

- [Overriding static methods in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617408/overriding-static-methods-in-java)
- [Javaのドキュメンテーション](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

---

一方、Pythonで似たようなコードを書いてみます。

```
class A(object): 
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("A.a()")

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("B.a()")
```

これはオーバーライドなのでしょうか?

**質問:**

- 上記のPythonコード例はオーバーライドと考えるべきか否か? その判断の根拠は?
- staticmethodではなく、classmethodや普通のメソッドの場合は?
- 一般に動的言語でどう考えるべきか?

Answer (score 5):

ちょっと乱暴な回答になりますが、より良い回答がつくまでのつなぎにどうぞ。

> 上記のPythonコード例はオーバーライドと考えるべきか否か? その判断の根拠は?

考えて良いでしょう。以下のコードでは、ベースクラス `A` にスタティックメソッド `a()` を呼び出すインスタンスメソッド `call_a()` を追加し、`B` のインスタンスの `call_a()` を呼んだ時、`B.a()` が実行されています。これが根拠です。

```
class A(object): 
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("A.a()")

    def call_a(self):
        self.a()

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("B.a()")

p = B()
p.call_a()    # B.a()
```

> staticmethodではなく、classmethodや普通のメソッドの場合は?

`classmethod` については同様の方法で実験してみてください。
普通のメソッドについては、当然オーバーライドとみなせます。

> 一般に動的言語でどう考えるべきか?

OOP の基本に立ち返ると「オーバーライドができる」というのは、
「あるメッセージに対する既存の振る舞いを変更=上書きできる」ということです。

最初の例はまさにそれを確認する作業で
仮に `call_a()` がBのインスタンスに対しても `A.a()` を呼び出すようならば、
これは振る舞いを変更できなかったことになるので、
オーバーライドできていないとなるわけです。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。動的型付の言語で、オーバーライドではなく隠蔽がおきるというのがそもそもありえないのでしょうか? (それがどういう状況なのかよくわからないのですが....)

Comment: OOP用語における「隠蔽(=カプセル化)」はまったく別の意味になってしまいます。動的言語であろうが無かろうが、あるオブジェクトのメッセージに対する振る舞い(=メソッド)を書き換えられるかどうかが、オーバーライドできるか判断の要点です。

Comment: いまいち理解できていないのですが、動的型付の言語で"オーバライドが起ない"例のようなものはありますでしょうか?

Comment: 動的型付け言語では、型単位のオーバーライドを禁止する方法は考えにくく、Pythonはありません。Rubyは `method_added` を使って裏技的にできそうです。JavaScriptは、型単位ではできませんが、インスタンス単位では `defineProperty` で読み込み専用にすることで、オーバーライドを禁じられます。

Answer (score 4):

オーバーライドとはメソッドを置き換えて動作をカスタマイズすることで、ハイディングとは、クラスに限らず、広いスコープの名前より狭いスコープの名前が優先され、通常の方法では広いスコープ側を参照できなくすることです。

Java のサンプルコードがオーバーライドでないのは、次のような場合に B クラスの a メソッドが呼ばれず、カスタマイズに失敗しているからです。

```
class A {
    public static void a() { 
        System.out.println("A.a()");
    }
    public static void b() {
        a();
    }
}   

class B extends A {
    public static void a() {
        System.out.println("B.a()");
    }
}

B.b();  // -> A.a() が表示される
```

一方、このコードがハイディングになっているのは、 B クラス内で普通に `a()` を呼び出した時に `A.a()` ではなく `B.a()` が呼ばれるようになっているからです。

Python の staticmethod の場合だと、 KoRoN さんの例ではカスタマイズに成功しているのですが、 `call_a()` を staticmethod にした場合にカスタマイズに失敗しています。なので、これがオーバーライドになっているかどうかは `a()` の呼び出し方によります。

```
class A(object): 
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("A.a()")

    @staticmethod
    def call_a():
        A.a()

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("B.a()")

p = B()
p.call_a()    # A.a()
```

一方、 Python の classmethod の場合、呼び出し元が classmethod でもカスタマイズに成功していて、なおかつあえて staticmethod ではなく classmethod を利用しているのはカスタマイズを可能にする目的があるので、完全にオーバーライドと呼べるでしょう。

このように、「オーバーライドかハイディングか」は、カスタマイズを目的としているか否かで判断するのが良いと思います。

余談ですが、次のような場合は明確にオーバーライドではなくハイディングです。

```
x = 3

def a(x):
    print x

a(5)  # 5
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示されたコードだと、`p.call_a()`が動かないと思いますが...

Comment: ごめんなさい、 staticmethod 化したのに self を受け取るままになってました。コードを修正しました。

Comment: あーそうか隠蔽ってhindingのほうか。ごめんなさい。目に入っていませんでした。overrideとhindingの区別については、methaneさんの説明にある「カスタマイズを目的としているか否か」に完全同意です。